# Como passar dados do DataGridView para o ReportViewer

Tags: c#

Preciso passar dados do `DataGridView` para o `ReportViewer` para fazer impressão, mas como sou novato ainda em c# não estou conseguindo passar o `datatable` para o form do `ReportViewer`, se alguém puder me explicar um passo a passo eu agradeço.

segue o meu código do `DataGridView`

```
private void bln_gerar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SqlCommand geracomissao = new SqlCommand("usp_RelatorioComissao", conexaoDADOSADV(true));
        geracomissao.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VENDEDOR", this.txt_vendedor.Text);
        geracomissao.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DTINICIAL", this.txt_dtinicial.Text);
        geracomissao.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DTFINAL", this.txt_dtfinal.Text);
        geracomissao.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        geracomissao.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

        SqlDataAdapter dados = new SqlDataAdapter(geracomissao);
        DataTable dtLista = new DataTable();
        dados.Fill(dtLista);

        dgw_comissao.DataSource = dtLista;

        dgw_comissao.Columns["NOTA"].ReadOnly = true;
        dgw_comissao.Columns["CLIENTE"].ReadOnly = true;
        dgw_comissao.Columns["PRODUTO"].ReadOnly = true;
        dgw_comissao.Columns["VALOR PARCELA"].ReadOnly = true;
        dgw_comissao.Columns["PARCELA S/ IMPOSTO"].ReadOnly = true;
        dgw_comissao.Columns["VENCIMENTO"].ReadOnly = true;
        dgw_comissao.Columns["PREÇO VENDA"].ReadOnly = true;
        dgw_comissao.Columns["COMISSÃO VENDEDOR"].Visible = false;
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Não exstem dados digitados para a consulta, por favor verificar!!!");
        return;
    }
}
```

segue o código do form onde estou colocando o `ReportViewer`.

```
public partial class frmImpRelatorioComissao : Form
{
    public frmImpRelatorioComissao()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void frmImpRelatorioComissao_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.rpw_comissao.RefreshReport();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa criar e inicializar corretamente o DataSource específico para o ReportView: [`ReportDataSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.reportdatasource.aspx).

O ReportDataSource irá representa uma fonte de dados (válida) para um relatório.

Ao chamar o form do report, passe como parâmetro o DataTable (que está no form 1).

[Atualizei a resposta com uma sugestão melhor. Adicionei também o código para a chamada do form]

**Formulário inicial**
Depois de preencher o DataTable (dtLista) com o SqlDataAdapter (dados), instancia o form do report e preenche a propriedade dataTable.

```
private void bln_gerar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SqlCommand geracomissao = new SqlCommand("usp_RelatorioComissao", conexaoDADOSADV(true));
        geracomissao.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VENDEDOR", this.txt_vendedor.Text);
        geracomissao.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DTINICIAL", this.txt_dtinicial.Text);
        geracomissao.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DTFINAL", this.txt_dtfinal.Text);
        geracomissao.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        geracomissao.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

        SqlDataAdapter dados = new SqlDataAdapter(geracomissao);
        DataTable dtLista = new DataTable();
        dados.Fill(dtLista);

        dgw_comissao.DataSource = dtLista;

        dgw_comissao.Columns["NOTA"].ReadOnly = true;
        dgw_comissao.Columns["CLIENTE"].ReadOnly = true;
        dgw_comissao.Columns["PRODUTO"].ReadOnly = true;
        dgw_comissao.Columns["VALOR PARCELA"].ReadOnly = true;
        dgw_comissao.Columns["PARCELA S/ IMPOSTO"].ReadOnly = true;
        dgw_comissao.Columns["VENCIMENTO"].ReadOnly = true;
        dgw_comissao.Columns["PREÇO VENDA"].ReadOnly = true;
        dgw_comissao.Columns["COMISSÃO VENDEDOR"].Visible = false;

        //Neste momento, o formulário do report será chamado passando 
        //para a propriedade o DataTable já preenchido.
        frmImpRelatorioComissao frmReport = new frmImpRelatorioComissao();
        frmReport.dataTable = dtLista;
        frmReport.Show();
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Não exstem dados digitados para a consulta, por favor verificar!!!");
        return;
    }
}
```

**Formulário do Report**
Foi criada uma propriedade para receber o datatable existente no form1.

```
public partial class frmImpRelatorioComissao : Form
{
    public DataTable dataTable{ get; set; }

    public frmImpRelatorioComissao()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void frmImpRelatorioComissao_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rprtDTSource = new ReportDataSource(dataTable.TableName, dataTable); 
        this.rpw_comissao.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rprtDTSource); 
        this.rpw_comissao.RefreshReport(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Ismael desculpe minha ignorância kk nessa pergunta, mas como passo como parâmetro o meu datatable que esta no form1..

Comment: Em que momento você abre o form do report? Ou seja, quando você dá `new frmImpRelatorioComissao`?

Comment: @JuniorGuerreiro Atualizei a resposta com uma forma mais prática e também adicionei um exemplo de como chamar o form.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda.